# How to have single instance of a bloc across other blocs

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

How can I avoid creating another instance of some bloc class?
I have two blocs: `LoginBloc` and `AuthBloc` . and LoginBloc accepts an instance of AuthBLoc and here is problem:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final UserRepository repository=UserRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => LoginBloc(
              //******Extra Instance of AuthBloc in being created here because LoginBloc needs it to listen********
              authBloc: AuthBloc(SInitialState(),userRepository: repository), userRepository:repository
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => AuthBloc(SInitialState(),userRepository: repository),
          )
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `AuthBloc` to a variable inside `build()` method.

Or, just nest one `BlockProvider` inside another one:

```dart
  BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
    create: (context) => AuthBloc(SInitialState(),userRepository: repository),
    child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState authState) { 
        return BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => LoginBloc(
              authBloc: context.bloc<AuthBloc>(), 
              userRepository: repository,
            ),
          child: MaterialApp(...),
          )
        })
      ),
```

But the best solution is [Bloc to Bloc communication](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)

Answer (score 0):

if I got you question correctly, you might use  [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)
and here is a sample code

```
MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<SginInBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => sl<SginInBloc>(),
          child: SginInPage(),
        ),....
```

so that you will get access to the instans of that Bloc that will be created

```
 final sl = GetIt.instance;
  sl.registerFactory(() => SginInBloc();
```

here I'm using **registerFactory** but you can use **registerSingleton** depends on what you want to achive

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  final UserRepository repository=UserRepository();
  runApp(MyApp(authBloc: AuthBloc(),userRepo : repository));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthBloc authBloc;
  final UserRepository userRepo;
  MyApp({required this.authBloc,required this.userRepo});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => LoginBloc(
              //******Extra Instance of AuthBloc in being created here because LoginBloc needs it to listen********
              authBloc: authBloc,userRepository: userRepo), userRepository:userRepo
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => authBloc,
          )
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(...);
```

Try this